# StringBuilder - replace existing string entirely. Any method?

Tags: java, string, replace, stringbuilder, overwrite

I see String usage in the existing code with several concatenation. Sonar code coverage recommends using StringBuilder. I am updating the code to use StringBuilder. But I am wondering how to efficiently overwrite the existing content with a new string.

In the string representation, its like below:

```
String query = "select...";
if ( x ) {
    query = "select xyz...";
}
```

With StringBuilder, I used this:

```
 StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select...");
 if ( x ) {
     // I need to overwrite the existing stringbuilder content here
     query = new StringBuilder("Select xyz..");
        //or
     query = query.replace(,,,);
        //or
     //Anything better
 }
```

I was hoping there would be a method like:

```
 query.replace("new string");
```

which overwrites entire existing string with the new string. But it is not available.

Comment: You should not use StringBuilder for that.

Comment: I agree, there is no easy way other than to `.delete().append()`... I wish `StringBuilder` had `.clear()` :(

Comment: @fge Yes, thats what I thought. Its a very common usecase.

Comment: @SLaks Whats the other alternative, close to String?

Comment: With the given example code, does it make more sense to construct the query as you go, rather than replace it altogether when x is true. Is there a way you can start the query with what is held in common between them, then if x is true complete it with the rest of the query for that case, otherwise complete it for the other case?

Comment: @ScottShipp Yes, thats a good way to deal with it. But my hands are tied here. I am supposed to just update the piece of a big pile of code. Don't want to touch entire thing.

Comment: " I wish StringBuilder had .clear()" : You can do .setLength(0)

Answer (score 11):

```
query.replace(0,query.length(), "new string");
```

Should work.

Comment: I am aware of this. Is that the only method? Its not straightforward.

Comment: In the standard library, I am afraid so.

Comment: Its too bad there isn't a `query.set("new string");` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, not the most elegant one, using `StringBuilder.replace(int start, int end, String str)` 
Let's say there are two conditions:

- Condition1: you want to replace "**ele**" with "**xxx**"
- Condition2: you want to replace "**...**" with "**yyy**"

Try the following

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select...");
String x = "ele";

String term1 = "ele";
String newTerm1 = "xxx";
String term2 = "...";
String newTerm2 = "yyy";

if ( x.equals(term1) ) {
    int start = query.indexOf(term1);
    int end = start + term1.length();
    query.replace(start, end, newTerm1);

}
else if (x.equals(term2)){
    int start = query.indexOf(term2);
    int end = start + term2.length();
    query.replace(start, end, newTerm2);
}
System.out.println(query.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

For your usecase the following seems perfect:

```
private static final String SELECT_PRE = "Select";
private static final String SELECT_POST = "...";
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(SELECT_PREFIX+SELECT_POST);
if ( x ) {
     query = query.insert(SELECT_PREFIX.length(), " xyz");
}
```